# converting a textfile into a list on python

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, split, text-files

```
def prepositions():
    file = open('prepositions.txt', 'r')
    thetext = [line.split(',') for line in file.readlines()]
    for line in file.readlines():
        row.append([line])
        for i in line.split(","):
            row[-1].append(i)
            print(prepositions)
```

I have a file named prepostions.txt that contains prepositions seperated by commas, for example:

afraid of,aim at,apprehensive of,approve of,article on   ...etc.

I'm trying to turn it into a list and print out the list but when I run the code above nothing is printed out, even though no errors come up.
So for example, I want it to print the following and save it as a list in a variable:

afraid of

aim at

apprehensive of

approve of

article on

Comment: Why do you read the file twice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you need to read the file twice? Read it once and transform it into the list:

```
def prepositions():
    items = []
    with open('test.txt') as input:
        for line in input:
            items.extend(line.strip().split(','))
    return items

print(prepositions())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
file = open('prepositions.txt', 'r')
thetext = [line.split(',') for line in file.readlines()]
```

after you do this file pointer is at the end.So next readlines() will not work.Use `file.seek(0)` before second readlines and there are loads of errors.Use this instead

```
def prepositions():
    file = open('input.txt', 'r')
    return [line.split(',') for line in file.readlines()]

print(prepositions)
```

Comment: OP's code will still not work even after fixing this problem... consider rephrasing

Comment: `row` is not defined within the function (but may be elsewhere), `prepositions` is not defined when it clearly should be, and `thetext` is defined but not used. Also `row` will contain both the full text of each line plus the parts of it, which is probably not the desired outcome.

Answer (score 0):

```
#The filename
filen = "awesome.txt"
#convert line into the list
lines = [line.strip() for line in open(str(filen))]
#getting line count and print out
with open(str(filen)) as f:
    c = sum(1 for _ in f)
i=0
n=int(c)
while i < n:
    print (str(lines[int(i)])) 
    i=i+1
```

I dont know if this helps so if the text file is structured like this then this is your answer :D :

hello 
cool
make me happy
be cool
whatever
and so on

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
def prepositions():
    with open('prepositions.txt', 'r') as myFile:
        prepositions = myFile.read().split(",").split("\n")
    for preposition in prepositions:
        print preposition
```

Your problem seems to be you never define row, i.e. :

```
row = []
```

meaning you keep overwriting it and at the end you come up with an emplty list because the last value you appended is either an empty line or white space.